# Half blank screen on ResponsiveUI in SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

The SlidingMenu demo app from the PlayStore works without any problem on my N7. But when I compile it from my computer, I have the following problem in ResposiveUI Activity : when I open the SlidingMenu on Portrait and change the orientation to Lanscape Mode... half screen is blank !

[image: ResposiveUI in Portrait Mode] 
[image: ResponsiveUi in Landscape Mode]

I didn't change anything in code except extending SherlockFragmentActivity as adviced [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/145) by the author.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd advise against using anything but the official implementation. It's also significantly better for performance.

Comment: It could be a good idea but I guess Navigation Drawer can't stay open without hiding content on big screens. SlidingMenu does.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Didn't know that though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that SlidingMenu is still open when screen is rotating. Closing it before Saving Instant State solves the problem.

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        showContent();
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the half blank screen is cased by SlidingMenu demo source code 70 line.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/fragments/ResponsiveUIActivity.java

You can modify it to

```
        if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) {
            sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        else
            sm.setBehindOffset(getScreenWidth());
```

getScreenWidth()

```
  public int getScreenWidth() {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.getMetrics(metrics);
            return metrics.widthPixels;
    }
```